# can't download image from web

Tags: objective-c, networking, uiimage

So I have this method to download an image from imgur.com as shown below:

```
- (void)getImageForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"i.imgur.com/%@.jpg",
                                     [self.IDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    self.imageTest = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
}
```

and then log the size of the data with this:

```
NSLog(@"%lx", (unsigned long)imageData.length);
```

but the size of the image in the log says

0

previously I use this asynchronous method:

```
- (void)getImageForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"i.imgur.com/%@.jpg",
                                     [self.IDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        UIImage *imageMain = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        self.imageTest = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        self.imageTest = [self imageWithImage:imageMain forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }];
    self.imageTest = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
}
```

but the log also says 0

yes the url exist. I have log it in another another method it is: i.imgur.com/EXtwoxT you can see for yourself

What did I do wrong? how do I check that the image has been downloaded properly?

EDIT :

for those who says it's the URL you can see my actual log below. you can copy&paste the URL in your browser to see if it exist (it does)

```
- (void)getImageForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"i.imgur.com/%@.jpg",
                                     [self.IDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    NSLog(@"i.imgur.com/%@.jpg", [self.IDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    //Asynchronous handler
//    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
//                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
//                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
//            UIImage *imageMain = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
//            self.imageTest = [[UIImage alloc] init];
//            self.imageTest = [self imageWithImage:imageMain forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//            NSLog(@"%lx", (unsigned long)imageData.length);
//        }];

    //Synchronous handler
    NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    self.imageTest = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
    NSLog(@"%lx", (unsigned long)imageData.length);
}

2015-01-06 07:44:26.564 Huckleberry[12733:361944] i.imgur.com/EXtwoxT.jpg
2015-01-06 07:44:26.600 Huckleberry[12733:361944] 0
```

Comment: I dam sure problem is in your image URL.

Comment: @samitarmum: check your URL is valid or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your code is missing a protocol for the URL -- NSURL can handle different protocols and doesn't just default to `http`.  Prefix `http://` to your URL and see if that gets you some data.

Secondly, that URL isn't actually the URL of the image -- I believe that URL will return the whole HTML imgur page, which is most likely not what you want (since you're trying to create a `UIImage` with the data).

Instead, try looking into the Imgur API (https://api.imgur.com) -- there's even a link on that page to an example Obj-C library (https://github.com/geoffmacd/ImgurSession)

Comment: actually the imgur API only gives you the image ID which I put in an array. imgur API doesn't give you the download capability, it only gives you the link and we have to download the image manually. but i think it's the missing http:// thats causing the problem.

Comment: This link suggests there's a way to get a direct link to the image using the API: https://api.imgur.com/models/image

But, if my answer already solved your question, please consider accepting it (or uprooting it) (I see you're new to Stack Overflow, so you may not know yet that's the normal practice)